# custom android navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I want to create an Android app using the navigation drawer, something like Google Maps, Gmail ecc. I know how to realize that, but I want something different. I would that the navigation bar is not completely hidden but it has to shows the icon always.

Is possible to realize this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be realizable using a SlidingPaneLayout (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) instead of the NavigationDrawer.

Here is an example of a SlidingPaneLayout:
http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/01/partial-slidingpanelayout.html

Comment: yes is something like that but it doesn't work. I'm looking for a "mini variant" of a Navigation Drawer of Google Patterns.

Comment: google don't document how to use the mini variant of the navigation drawer, so I used the Sliding Panel Layout, so your answer is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Navigation Drawer, the Android Design Library has a new component called NavigationView. [[Refer Link]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html)

A sweet tutorial of the Android Design Library by Chris Banes is available at this page. [GitHub - Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

You might want to refer to the Google I/O app if you want a custom feel to your Nav Drawer. github.com/google/iosched

EDIT: Considering you use the NavigationView and want to make the text transparent on being selected, add a new file in /res/color/. Let's name it nav_item_text.xml

Use the following content in it:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Text color when checked -->
    <item android:color="#00000000" android:state_checked="true" />

    <!-- Text color when not checked. Modify value to color of primary text. -->
    <item android:color="#212121" />
</selector>
```

And then add this to your NavigationView layout:

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_text"
```

It will now look like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_text"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav"/>
```

If you want to make the text gone always:

```
app:itemTextColor="#00000000"
```